# 'delete_option()' only deleting the value, not the key/value pair

Tags: options, settings-api

Recently a plugin I am developing begun throwing up an error whenever I deleted the plugin options (restored them to default).

I'm using the Settings API within the plugin in question, and on another page I am checking the settings assigned to those options -

```
$login_settings = get_option('fgw_login', array());
```

Upon activation and after I save the settings this was workin fine, with the default `array()` being assigned to `$login_settings` if required.

However I was getting an error whenever I tried to reset the plugin options to their defaults. Basically I wanted to delete the key/value pair from the `wp_options` database.

```
/**
 * Sanitize the option on save
 */
public function on_save_settings($input){

    /** Check to see if the options should be restored to default */
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])) :
        delete_option('fgw_login');
        return;
    endif;

    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) return;    // Ensure the user is supposed to be here

    {more stuff here, but not relevant}

}
```

However it seemed that `delete_option('fgw_login');` wasn't actually deleting the key/value pair for the option, but rather just the value, leaving the key in place.

This was a problem because I was checking the `$login_settings` for a specific array key value, but as `$login_settings` was being set as an empty string I was getting an error.

I could have simply added a check to see if `$login_settings` was an array, but I was curious so I did some digging.  If you are at all interested, please see my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was caused because I was using a sanitize callback declared in `register_settings()` (the `on_save_chages()` function below).

This callback will ultimatly update the database with whatever value is returned, creating the `fgw_login` key if it does not exist.

To ensure that I always had my default empty array if required I made the following simple change, returning an empty array when the options were reset as opposed to nothing -

```
/**
 * Sanitize the option on save
 */
public function on_save_settings($input){

    /** Check to see if the options should be restored to default */
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])) :
        delete_option('fgw_login');
        return array();                 /** <-- THIS IS ALL I HAD TO DO */
    endif;

    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) return;    // Ensure the user is supposed to be here

    {more stuff here, but not relevant}

}
```

While the problem exposed my code for not making the proper checks, I'm glad that I was afforded the oppurtunity to delve into the Settings API in greater depth and encourage any users of it's awesomeness to do the same :)